# What is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^3+1}dx$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I am told to compute the above integral in terms of its principal value. My method involved using a semi-circular contour on the upper half plane, with an indentation around $-1$, as this is a singularity. The maths reduces to the following;

$$PV\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^3+1}dx = 2{\pi} i \mbox{Res}\left(\frac{1}{z^3+1}, e^{\frac{{\pi}i}{3}} \right) +{\pi}i \mbox{Res}\left(\frac{1}{z^3+1},-1\right) = \cdots = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}$$

And after computing the residues, which are found in a straightforward manner as they are both simple poles, I get the answer of $\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}$.

However, Wolfram doesn't give an answer for it. It says that the integral doesn't converge. Thus, I can't be sure my answers correct.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha doesn't know how to do principal value integrals, so it's telling you (correctly) that the standard integral doesn't converge.   Try telling it to manually calculate $\int_{-\infty}^{-(1+\epsilon)} \frac{dx}{x^3+1}$ and $\int_{(1+\epsilon)}^\infty \frac{dx}{x^3+1}$.  Then add them and take the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$ (this is the definition of the principal value integral.)  Note that you will need to add "assuming $\epsilon > 0$" to your queries to get a result.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B1%2F%281+%2B+x%5E3%29%2C+%7Bx%2C+-%5C%5BInfinity%5D%2C+%5C%5BInfinity%5D%7D%2C+++PrincipalValue+-%3E+True%5D

Comment: Maple agrees with $\pi/\sqrt3$ from `int(1/(x^3+1),x=-infinity..infinity,CauchyPrincipalValue=true);`

Answer (score 3):

The integral diverges indeed in common sense. When you use indentation, you actually calculate the principal value of the integral
$$
\text{p.v.}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^3+1} = \frac\pi{\sqrt{3}}
$$

Thus, you need to use `PrincipalValue` option in Wolfram Mathematica to calculate it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can use decomposition into simple fractions $${1\over x^3+1}={1\over 3(x+1)} -{x-{1\over 2}\over 3\left [(x-{1\over 2})^2+{3\over 4}\right ]}+{1\over 2\left [(x-{1\over 2})^2+{3\over 4}\right ]}$$
Then $$PV\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty {dx\over x+1}=PV\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty {dx\over x}=0,$$  $$PV\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty{x-{1\over 2}\over (x-{1\over 2})^2+{3\over 4}}\,dx=PV\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty{x\over x^2+{3\over 4}}\,dx=0,$$ as the integrated functions are odd and tend to $0$ at  $\pm \infty.$ Next $$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty {dx\over 2\left [(x-{1\over 2})^2+{3\over 4}\right ]}={1\over \sqrt{3}}\arctan {2\over \sqrt{3}}\left (x-{1\over 2}\right ) \Big |_{-\infty}^\infty ={\pi\over \sqrt{3}}. $$
By $$ PV \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx,$$  where $f(x)$ has sigularity at $x=0$ and tends to $0$ at $\pm \infty,$ I mean
$$\lim_\underset{\Large\varepsilon \to 0^+}{N\to \infty}\left [\int\limits_{-N}^{-\varepsilon} f(x)\,dx + \int\limits_{\varepsilon}^N f(x)\,dx\right ]$$

Answer (score 0):

Try to applying the simple fractions decomposition or multiplie by $3x^2$   we get
$$ \int \dfrac{3x^2}{3x^2(x^3+1)}$$ and  use the partial integral.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).